# How to separate a form into several different pages when using a single class component spfx/react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I've got a single class component and I want to create a next and previous button which skips through different pages. I don't want a long form and find the buttons necessary.
I have created an spfx webpart which uses a single stateful class component. The render has all the fields in it. I've looked on online and seen that separating the fields into separate components is the best way to do this and have a parent container comp. and several child comps. I don't want to do this. Reason? I'm learning how to do this in a separate project so for this project need to do it this way.

Is there a simple way to split up the render's fields so when a next button is clicked it hides page 1 and then shows page 2? Remember all these fields are within the same render! I'm fine with the logic for this but need to know if there is something that can be put into the render such as 
`<Form />` to break it up into different forms, then run a ternary conditional on that?

Comment: could you share some of your code and what you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can understand is that for a long form which has a lot of input fields in it and you want to have a previous next functionality which will hide some fields and show the required fields according to the button click.

What you can do is by maintaining a state property like 'PageNo' and you can maintain the page number in that state parameter and when you'll click on the next/prev button, you can write simple logic to increase and decrease the PageNo value.

As you don't want to maintain various components for various pages, so you can have the whole code written on one single page and you can manipulate the show/hide of the container divs by the value of 'PageNo' state parameter.

Like,

```
<div style={{ display: this.state.PageNo == 1 ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
// Page 1 Content goes here
</div>
<div style={{ display: this.state.PageNo == 2 ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
// Page 2 Content goes here
</div>
<div style={{ display: this.state.PageNo == 3 ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
// Page 3 Content goes here
</div>
```

So, Like this you can achieve the required functionality.

But, The best way to do it by maintaining separate child components for every page and one parent component for navigating btw. pages.